# How to reformat dates?

Tags: date, sas, format

Hello currently my dates are stored as numeric in the form of 40547.  How can I convert these to MMDDYY10.?

```
data SevenSec11;
      set Seven11;
      DateRecieved = input(put(DateRecieved, 8.), MMDDYY10.);
      format DateRecieved MMDDYY10.;
 run;
```

Comment: What date does 40,547 represent? SAS stores dates as the number of days since 1960 so that would be in the year 2071.  If you know what your basis for those numbers are then just subtract the right number.

Comment: Does this date represent 04/05/1947?

Answer (score 1):

How to convert it depends on what the value represents.  If it is dates as stored by Excel then change the offset value.  If it is supposed to represent MMDDYY values then use the `Z6.` format in your `PUT()` function call.

```
data test;
  input num ;
  sasdate1 = num + '30DEC1899'd ;
  sasdate2 = input(put(num ,z6.),mmddyy10.);
  format num comma7. sasdate: yymmdd10. ;
cards;
40547
;
```

Result:

```
Obs        num      sasdate1      sasdate2

 1      40,547    2011-01-04    1947-04-05
```

Note that using Y-M-D order for dates will eliminate confusion that truncated leading zeros can cause. It will also prevent half of your audience from confusing April 5th with May 4th.